# Create a "next record/previous record" button in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app with one controller managing an *index* template displaying records received from an API call and a second controller managing the corresponding *show* template for a record.

I'd like to create a forward/backward button on the *show* template so that you can simply skip through the records.  If I reach the end, I would like it to restart at the beginning - and endless loop.

I am not sure where to place the logic of "total number of records" so that my show controller knows that I've reached the end.  Only my index controller has the complete set of data.  It seems that services are useful in making controllers speak, but I'm not sure how to implement it for this case.

**API call currently happening in a factory:**

```
app.factory('studentsFactory', ['$http', '$cacheFactory', function ($http, $cacheFactory) {

  var factory = {};

  factory.getStudents = function() {
    return $http.get('http://localhost:3000/students', { cache: true });   };

  factory.getStudent = function(studentId) {
    return $http.get('http://localhost:3000/students/' + studentId, { cache: true });   };

  return factory;

}]);
```

**...and handing off to an IndexCtrl:**

```
app.controller('IndexCtrl', ['$scope', 'studentsFactory', function ($scope, studentsFactory) {

  function init() {
    studentsFactory.getStudents()
      .success(function (students) {
        $scope.students = students;
        $scope.length = students.length
      });
    });
  }

  init();
}]);
```

**...and a ShowCtrl:**

```
app.controller('ShowCtrl', ['$scope', 'studentsFactory', '$routeParams', function ($scope, studentsFactory, $routeParams){
  var studentId = $routeParams.studentId;
  // var nextId = studentId++  (if < max, go ahead, if not, reset to 1)

  function init() {
    studentsFactory.getStudent(studentId)
      .success(function (student) {
        $scope.student = student;
      });
  });

  init();
}]);
```

Seems like it's right in front of me.  Any chance the factory can also send data from the same API call to a service that could store a max as a variable?

Many thanks.

Comment: actually, the `studentsFactory` has the whole set of data too, and so does $cache after it's been called. Why not add a `length` method or property to the factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put some next and previous methods in the service, close to the student data itself.  Maybe something like:

```
factory.nextStudent = function() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  rollIndexForward();
  this.getStudent(currentIndex).then(function(student) {
    deferred.resolve(student);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
};

factory.previousStudent = function() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  rollIndexBackward();
  this.getStudent(currentIndex).then(function(student) {
    deferred.resolve(student);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

Then you can tie these to next() and previous() methods in your controller to set the current student.

```
$scope.next = function() {
  studentsFactory.nextStudent().then(function(student) { 
    $scope.currentStudent = student;
  });
};

$scope.previous = function() {
  studentsFactory.previousStudent().then(function(student) { 
    $scope.currentStudent = student;
  });
}
```

This keeps the student gathering logic together and will enable reuse.

There's a plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/YPqfIDX8USeg0jv6nlGi?p=preview

Comment: This is wonderful. I like keeping all of this logic close. One question of clarification -- rather than having an array of students in my factory, I'm making an API call and shipping the success data directly to the controller to be dealt with.  It doesn't appear that my factory has access to the success data (...or does it?).  Not sure what I'm missing to capture it's size before it leaves. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I'm using the array to get around the need to mock out the $http calls that you make.  You should keep that part of your code the same.

Comment: I've changed this slightly, services should hide their implementations from their callers.  Edited above.